# Usability of applications without the traditional "menu" bar

Tags: windows, user-interface

I've noticed recently that it seems to be a trend in Windows applications to no longer include the menu bar in an application (the "File  Edit ..." menu), instead having the functionality linked to icons seemingly randomly spread around the application window.
for example: IE8, Windows 7 media player.

Is there any usability evidence driving this change? (I, personally, find these apps really hard to use)

If so, can someone suggest where I might find this research and perhaps some guidelines for writing new applications using this style?

Some answers have suggested that it's the "Ribbon" style, which appears to be what I'm looking at. I'm still having trouble finding guidelines or evidence of what works/doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a quick search I found a reasonable explanation of this UI trend. It is based on the Ribbon concept. It traces back from Office 2007 and even Firefox is using it.

References:
http://www.pcpro.co.uk/news/351808/firefox-tidies-up-with-office-2007s-ribbon
http://slashdot.org/story/09/09/23/1846248/Firefox-To-Replace-Menus-Wi
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Sprints/Windows_Theme_Revamp/Direction_and_Feedback
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_(computing)

Comment: the Wikipedia article was interesting and seems to imply that the guidelines/evidence I'm after may be locked away behind some licensing/patent wall?

Comment: well, about the patent thing there are a lot of thing involved like you saw in wikipedia the Microsoft Guidelines is not opensource, KDE thought to sue Microsoft, another guys with similar features. Due the vast use of this UI appeal, I think you have no problem to use it, but no guidelines is available from M$.

Answer (score 5):

The MS Office Ribbon perhaps inspired the latest slew of apps that use multiple icons without text labels in lieu of a menu bar. However, the implementation of these apps apparently failed to understand or realize the advantages of the Ribbon or even what makes a Ribbon a Ribbon.

Controls labeled with icons alone are more difficult to learn than those labeled with text alone [See Wiedenbeck S (1999). The use of icons and labels in an end user application program: an empirical study of learning and retention. Behaviour & Information Technology, 18(2)]. The lack of text labels for *groups* of controls in these apps can’t help.

Note that the Office Ribbon generally avoids both of these pitfalls by providing text labels for groups of controls (the Office Logo being a notable exception) and text labels for most individual controls (many controls on the Home tab being another notable exception).

After being subject to much research, the Office Ribbon largely preserved the traditional File-Edit-View arrangement of commands found the traditional menu bar. There’s no evidence that there’s anything wrong with this organization.

IMO, icon-scattered UI designs represent a fashion or branding statement, a rather clumsy attempt to appear “state-of-the-art” like Office, and an excuse to decorate the UI with graphics. They are not a usability improvement.

For everything about the Ribbon, see [Jensen Harris’s blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/jensenh/archive/tags/Ribbon/default.aspx). 
My [critique of the Ribbon](http://www.zuschlogin.com/?p=36). Not that I'm particularly satisfied with the [traditional menu bar and tool bar](http://www.zuschlogin.com//?p=7).

Comment: Very interesting, so while the Office Ribbon is probably designed at least plausibly to improve usability, most of the other apps trying to copy it probably aren't. I think I'll stick to traditional menubar for now.

Answer (score 3):

It is [ribbon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_(computing)). Presumably it is easier to use than the standard menu because it is context dependent. The whole purpose of developing it was that despite the fact Word can do almost anything now, people were complaining it is missing some features just because they couldn't find them. So MS people were thinking hard and ribbon is what they created. Being context dependent it shows you the features you might use right now, not all the features and it saves screen estate so more features actually visible to the user.

Comment: I think it's important to understand that the ribbon isn't a replacement for the menu-and-toolbar, but a replacement for the menu-and-toolbar-when-there-are-too-many-functions. The ribbon seems to improve usability for extremely feature-rich applications but I think the jury is still out for the vast majority of apps. I think in most cases the menubar still reigns supreme.

Comment: I'd also like to add that from a usability standpoint, making the old menu available by pressing the alt-key is superb.  You can have your cake and eat it too.

Answer (score 0):

The ribbon still serves as a navigation area - a combination of a menubar and toolbar that tends to be organized by area (Print, Design, Layout, External Data) rather than traditional style (File, Edit, Tools).  While it does take a bit of getting used to things being organized by area, it certainly adds to the usability.

I think the reason IE 8 integrates the menu bar into the same line as the tab is to allow for more viewing real estate (or junky toolbar add-ons).  A ribbon would be overkill for something as simple as a browser where 99% of the time you do one of 3 things: Enter a URL, Go to Bookmarks/Favorites, or Print.

If you are writing a Windows-based database system or other complex application, definitely checkout how Microsoft utilizes the ribbons throughout its Office products.

Answer (score -1):

The "ribbon" is nothing more than a FAT toolbar. Such things are getting invented, not because of user request or need, but because of the arrogance of large corporations and bored, rich managers and "developers" sitting around with nothing to do. "Inventing" things is one thing, but FORCING it on everyone w/o preserving the previous, non-cluttered, classic, working, familiar interface is absolute arrogance. People need to be informed. You don't have to put up with it. Say something.